# What is this blank space on the Pokemon Summary page?

Tags: pokemon-go

Looking at the details of my Pokemon, I see a blank space between the date I caught it and the "transfer" button.

[image: Pokemon Detail]

What is this used for?  Should something be in this space that I'm not seeing?

I'm using an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.1 and Pokemon GO version 1.0.3.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Typically, the Map would be there, indicating the rough location of where that Pokemon was caught or its egg was collected.

[image: Pokemon Summary]

Source: [Viewing a Pokémon’s Summary](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049867-Viewing-a-Pok%C3%A9mon-s-Summary-)

However, due to the overwhelming traffic from players, the map and the "footsteps" were removed in order to relieve some of the pressure from Niantic's servers. Both of these features will be added back once the game calms down and Niantic gets more servers to run everything they need.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @JAL Trying to find a screenshot for you.

Comment: What about a source for the bug?

Comment: @JAL I'm sure it's present on a Niantic bug report somewhere.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to your answer with an official image and link to the support page.  Feel free to accept it if you feel it adds value.

Answer (score 5):

When the game first was released, I remember that spot being used for a cropped image of a map to indicate where you caught the Pokémon. However, I just opened the app, and I'm no longer seeing a map either. Probably a bug in the latest version of the app.