# Pokemon Go not showing where I capture the Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokemon go is not showing where the pokemons are captured, it is just showing a white section where the map should be, please help.

[image: it is just showing a blank page]

Comment: Mine started doing the same thing last week as well

Comment: Please keep in mind that the [pokemon-series] tag doesn't apply for Pokemon GO.

Comment: Related: [What is this blank space on the Pokemon Summary page?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276618/what-is-this-blank-space-on-the-pokemon-summary-page). Not quite a duplicate, but see the latter half of the accepted answer

Comment: @Wondercricket: I'd argue that it's a duplicate. The questions are essentially asking about the same thing, and the answer there perfectly answers this question.

Comment: @Ellesedil This question is asking *why is it blank?* , the other question is asking *What is the blank space?*. Different questions, similar answers

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug and hopefully they will fix it with a future update. I personally prefer this to be removed altogether as it allays messes up that page when I'm about to transfer.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the preferred removal. The mini-map typically shows inaccurate locations for me. I have a Pokemon that showed that I caught a Pokemon in one location, but found and hatched in two completely different locations

Comment: @Wondercricket Plus where you found the Pokemone does not mean you'll find another later on. I saw a youtube video that you get spawns every hour on the hour. That's not true, I tested.

Answer (score 0):

Niantic has temporarily removed this feature from the game (along with the footsteps) in order to attempt to make less work for the servers.

They should be returning again once the game settles down, and Niantic's servers are more capable of handling the game load.